# Error when running SSIS package with parameter - dtexec

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am facing issues when I run SSIS package with parameters but without parameter it works.

What could be the problem?

**Query without parameter-**

```
Begin

declare @query varchar(4000) = 
'dtexec /Project C:\SSIS\DUTPackages.ispac /Package cityTransfer.dtsx /decrypt password1!'

exec xp_cmdshell @query

End
```

**Query with parameter-**

```
Begin
declare @p_cityId varchar(10) = '%'
declare @p_count varchar(10) = '-1'

declare @query varchar(4000) = 
'dtexec /Project C:\SSIS\DUTPackages.ispac /Package cityTransfer.dtsx /decrypt password1!'
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[$Package::p_cityID];''' +  @p_cityId + ''''
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[$Package::p_count];''' + @p_count + ''

exec xp_cmdshell @query

End
```

**Error I get when running query with parameter-**

```
[OLE DB Source [25]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E10.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0202009.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need to add some double quotes and remove a couple single quotes. Try this:

```
Begin
declare @p_cityId varchar(10) = '%'
declare @p_count varchar(10) = '-1'

declare @query varchar(4000) = 
'dtexec /Project C:\SSIS\DUTPackages.ispac /Package cityTransfer.dtsx /decrypt password1!'
+ ' /SET "\Package.Variables[$Package::p_cityID];' +  @p_cityId + '"'
+ ' /SET "\Package.Variables[$Package::p_count];' + @p_count + '"'

exec xp_cmdshell @query

End
```

Answer (score 0):

In some instances, only the parameters need to be quoted with ". So try - `'" +  @p_cityId + "'`  and same for `@p_count`